# Automatic reboot to the another zone[GCE]

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to ask about the function of automatic reboot for GCE.
Google document says that if there are malfuntion or system failure in the host of GCE, GCE will be launched automatically in the another host of the same zone.

If there are zone level malfunction or systme failure, will GCE be launched automatically in the antoher zone?

Comment: No, that is what redundancy is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCE VM instance is bound to a zone. It won't fail over to another zone in case of the whole zone failure. To protect against zone failure you should implement HA cluster with nodes located in different zones.

You may consider [Regional Managed instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#types_of_managed_instance_groups) for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I will check Regional Managed instance groups.